# Changing color of vertical line using paracol and \setlength{\columnseprule}{}

Tags: latex

This works fine, except that I want to change the color of the vertical line separating the two columns.  Help?

I have seen comments that \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt} only works in a multicolumn environment.  It seems to work here, but how to change the color?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,                                                        %  Choose paper size
                    left=   1.0in,                                                      %  Set the margins                              
                    right= 1.0in,                                                       %
                    top=   1.5in,                                                       %
                    bottom=1.5in]{geometry}                                 %
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

 %---------------------------- Colors ----------------------------------------------------------------------------% 

\definecolor{CustomOrange}{rgb}{1, 0.43529, 0.01176}                                        % Define custom colors
\definecolor{CustomGrey}{rgb}{0.4745, 0.4745, 0.4745} 

\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{red}}

%---------------------------- Header ----------------------------------------------------------------------------% 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}                                  % Thickness of  header rule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{                    %
\color{CustomOrange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}            %

%---------------------------- Set Columns -----------------------------------------------------------------------%  

\setlength\headheight{52pt} 
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{./images/intendere}}

\columnsep=0.05\textwidth
\setcolumnwidth{.35\textwidth, .6\textwidth}                            % One entry for each column, see paracol{} below 

\tolerance=1                                                                                % Code fixes the justification issue with columns flowing over
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen                                                 %
\hyphenpenalty=10000                                                            %
\hbadness=10000                                                                     %

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

%---------------------------- Begin Document---------------------------------------------------------------------%  

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}  
    \lipsum 
    \switchcolumn
    \lipsum                                                                                 
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code works:

```
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.5pt}

\colseprulecolor{red}
```